# Determining the minimum angle of a baseball trajectory to get a home run

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, physics

This is a homework question:

> The skydome in Toronto has a center field fence that is 10 feet high and 400 feet from home plate.  A ball is hit 3 feet above the ground with an initial velocity of 100 miles per hour.
>
> a) The ball leaves the bat at an angle of $\theta = \theta_0$ with the horizontal.  Write a vector valued function for the path of the ball.

My answer after converting the miles per hour to feet/sec: $$r(t) = \langle 146.7\cos\theta_0t, -16t^2 + 146.7\sin\theta_0t + 3\rangle$$

> b) ... Draw some graphs and determine the minimum angle required for a home run.
>
> c) Determine analytically the minimum angle required for the hit to be a home run.

My answer:  I set $t = x / 146.7\cos\theta$, replaced t in the y component of the above vector, then solved for theta (Making the angle $\theta$ a function of x and y), but when I plug in $x = 400$ and $y = 10$ I get an unrealistic answer...

EDIT: Here is how I solved for $\theta$:
Solve for $t$ using the x-component of the vector and plug the result into the y component:
$$y = -16(x/146.7\cos\theta)^2 + 146.7\sin\theta(x/146.7\cos\theta) + 3$$
Here I actually solved for any x or y, but it's easier to plug them in now:
$10 = -119\sec^2\theta + 400\tan\theta + 3$
$7  = -119\tan^2\theta - 119 + 400\tan\theta$
$-0.06 = \tan^2\theta - 3.36\tan\theta$
$2.76 = (\tan\theta - 1.68)^2$
$3.34 = \tan\theta$
$\tan^{-1}3.34 = 73$

73 is obviously too high.

**Do I have the correct position function and how can I analytically determine the minimum angle required for a home run?**

Comment: Your formula is missing a $t$ on the page, but that's just because of a typo. Everything you have on here looks fine. What did you get after what you've typed up here?

Comment: Your working looks correct, but as you say, 74 can't be the only answer. The maximum distance is attained at 45 degrees (or it would be if the outfield fence was 3ft high), so your problem should have two solutions, one greater and one smaller than 45. I can't see where the smaller solution has gone!

Comment: Yes the smaller answer from subtracting the radical created after completing the square is far too small (about 1 degree).

Comment: @roundar: In fact it's negative.

Comment: -0.06 is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sec^2\theta = \tan^2\theta + 1$, not $\tan^2\theta-1$.

Comment: Thank you, forgot to carry the negative over.  Unfortunately the answer doesn't seem to be affected enough for this to be the significant error.

Comment: Yes it does. Now you get two answers, one greater and one smaller than 45 degrees (as predicted in my comment to your question).

Comment: Thank you very much, this and your pointing out the arithmetic error afterward solved the problem!